# Why does python statement yield behave this way with cursor?

Tags: python, cursor, mysql-python, yield

I have the following code (i know how to do this working and in the right style, but cited it as an example only to ask a question and understand where is mistake):

```py
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
connection = MySQLdb.connect(
        host=host, port=port, user=username, passwd=password, db=database, 
        cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = 'SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE'
cursor.execute(sql)

def gen():
    yield cursor.fetchmany(5)

for i in gen():
    print i
```

and second:

```py
def gen():
    yield 'spam'

for i in gen():
    print i

# Process finished with exit code 0
```

I can't understand why the second example is one time and ends as it should, but the first performed one time and then freezes and does nothing. Why he doesn't stop with exit code 0?

**Strange behavior**:
If to the second example add the following lines before cycle it prints 'spam' and "freezes" too:

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(
        host=host, port=port, user=username, passwd=password, db=database, 
        cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor)
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = 'SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE'
cursor.execute(sql)
```

**Update**
Answer: Python does not come out of the program as long as it's time connection is closed.

Comment: It is possible that the first one "freezes" if cursor.fetchmany(5) happens to be pulling from a large or slow database that is taking a long time to actually run the fetch once. Have you tried just running cursor.fetchmany(5) on it's own and seeing if that takes awhile?

Comment: Yes,you are right. On the local database the fisrt example gives a row in the output and finishes with exit code 0. But on the real big table(not local) the first gives a row and "freezes". Why not just end when he did the work?

Answer (score 1):

i think what you should do in first case is

```
result = cursor.fetchmany(5)

for item in result:
    yield item
```

`fetchmany` method fetches the next set of rows of a query results, returning a list of tuples.

An `empty list` is returned when no more rows are available.

Comment: The question was a little different, why the program does not finish the work in the first case? Expected as only one pass through the loop and exit.